# How to create a box in \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

Tags: tcolorbox, acmart

I want to create a box highlighting my findings in `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`. I found [authors](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3510003.3510049) on the internet can create a box that fits my need (please see attached image). I am aware that ACM also defined a list of accepted packages at https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages. My question is, which package from the list can give me the same result? As `tcolorbox` doesn't exist the list.

[image]

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox is allowed